# Unknown Alias error when running delayed_job

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

I'm running delayed_job 3.0.5 with delayed_job_active_record 0.4.4 and daemons 1.1.9 on Rails 3.2.14 with a MySQL DB. When I execute the script/delayed_job start command it appears to start up normally yet no pid file is created. When I check the delayed_job log, no error is in it just the informational message that the process is starting.

However, when I look at the rails dev log I see an Unknown alias return after the SQL update command. Here is a snip from my log showing where I started it delayed_job twice. Each time it got a new pid and each time it gave the same Unknown alias.

I'd appreciate any help in trying to solve this.

```
bcrossland-mb:GameKultur bcrossland$ tail log/development.log 
  Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (17.9ms)  SELECT `delayed_jobs`.* FROM `delayed_jobs` WHERE `delayed_jobs`.`locked_at` = '2013-09-18 21:14:09' AND `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = 'delayed_job host:bcrossland-mb.local pid:13163' AND `delayed_jobs`.`failed_at` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Preference Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `preferences`.* FROM `preferences` LIMIT 1
  SQL (8.0ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `locked_by` = NULL, `locked_at` = NULL WHERE `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = 'delayed_job host:bcrossland-mb.local pid:13163'
Unknown alias: 70352758094800
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
  SQL (105.9ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `locked_at` = '2013-09-18 21:36:58', `locked_by` = 'delayed_job host:bcrossland-mb.local pid:13564' WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-09-18 21:36:58' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-09-18 17:36:58') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:bcrossland-mb.local pid:13564') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
  Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `delayed_jobs`.* FROM `delayed_jobs` WHERE `delayed_jobs`.`locked_at` = '2013-09-18 21:36:58' AND `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = 'delayed_job host:bcrossland-mb.local pid:13564' LIMIT 1
  Preference Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `preferences`.* FROM `preferences` LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.8ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `locked_by` = NULL, `locked_at` = NULL WHERE `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = 'delayed_job host:bcrossland-mb.local pid:13564'
Unknown alias: 70352758094800
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It was a bad job in the delayed_jobs table. I have a module that every model includes for sending out mail on errors with running the model. It's been working for years however on a new model the error message being send is getting a string injected before the ruby call that is causing delayed_jobs to crash out.

```
- &70352758094800 !ruby/string
```

As you can see from the example, &70352758094800 is being injected in front of the ruby call the delayed_job is going to execute. The numbers match the numbers listed in the Unknown alias error. Since the string never changed, I decided to search the table for it and discovered this bad job. Once I delete the job from the table delayed_jobs started without an issue.